# SVN info command doesn't show the last commit author

Tags: svn

when I try to use the command

```
svn info
```

does not display the author of the last change.

There is something to be configured?

result of "svn --version"

```
svn, version 1.8.8 (r1568071)
   compiled Aug 13 2014, 17:12:39 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

result of "svn info"

```
Path: .
Working Copy Root Path: /var/www/html/cc
URL of repository: http://localhost/svn/ciro/trunk
Relative URL: ^/trunk
Repository: http://localhost/svn/ciro
UUID of Repository: xxxxxx-xxx-xxx-b655-xxxxx
Revision: 40
Node type: directory
Action: normal
Revision last change: 40
last change date: 2014-10-08 17:31:45 +0200 (mer, 08 ott 2014)
```

I translated the items in the response to use the English language requirement

Comment: Can you post the command you ran and the output?  Also the version of SVN you are using.

Comment: the command is `svn info` is write. edit question with additional info

Comment: That's odd. I'm running the exact same client version (but on Windows) and do get the author info. Have you tried: (1) checking out the same URL to a new working copy, (2) checking out a different folder in the same repo (3) checking out a different repo?

Comment: You may not have an author associated with revision 40.  Run `svn proplist --revprop --revision 40` and see if it lists "svn:author".

Comment: is patrick says. thanks for the support